# Unity 2D GameKit MovingPlatform not moving

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am learning Unity with the 2D GameKit Tutorials on Unity Learn. 
In that they use the MovingPlatform to move Ellen from one point to another.

When I place the MovingPlatform in the scene, it does not move whatsoever.

However, When ellen walks up to the MovingPlatform and walks on it, she's pushed in the direction of movement planned for the Platform. But platform doens't move, only ellen does.

Here's what is looks like. [Unity 2D GameKit MovingPlatform not moving.](https://imgur.com/a/SyMaswe)

Here's what the motion looks like. [Unity 2D GameKit MovingPlatform not moving.](https://imgur.com/a/pE5e2wu)

Comment: The issue is the frozen position constraints. see: [https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/2d-the-moving-platform-is-not-changing-position-in-game-mode-and-makes-only-character-move-forward-when-it-stands-on-it](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/2d-the-moving-platform-is-not-changing-position-in-game-mode-and-makes-only-character-move-forward-when-it-stands-on-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the same issue with a new install of 2019.2.9f1, and debugged through the code until it made a call to a Unity blackbox Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.

Since there's no way to chase that further I tried importing the same project into a new  install of 2019.1.14f1, and found that it works fine there.

Comment: Mine's 2019.2.f2 but seems like the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see it working in 2019.2, you can use this hack instead of MovePosition():
m_Rigidbody2D.position +=  direction.normalized * dist;
Inde

Answer (score 0):

Yes opening moving platforms.cs and replacing

m_Velocity = direction.normalized * dist;

with

m_Rigidbody2D.position += direction.normalized * dist;

works.